# How can we publish Aurora (Postgres compatible) logs to Cloudwatch?

Tags: aurora, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm looking for a way to publish Aurora (pg compatible) db logs to cloudwatch. 
In Postgres RDS, there is an option when we "modify" the instance to enable publishing db and upgrade logs to cloudwatch, however I see no such option in Aurora.

I found some documentation on how this can be achieved for Aurora MySQL but nothing for Aurora Postgres.

Is this currently feasible? Appreciate any help or pointers on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full Disclosure: I am the product manager for Aurora PostgreSQL.

We are working to add support for the feature you noticed that is already available for RDS for PostgreSQL and for Aurora MySQL, to automatically copy database logs to Cloudwatch. While I don’t have a date to communicate, we plan to launch this feature soon - stay tuned!

Kevin Jernigan
Principal Product Manager, Amazon Aurora with PostgreSQL Compatibility

Comment: Thanks Kevin! Hoping to see this feature soon.